# Using Option instead of NOT NULL in Slick

Tags: scala, h2, slick

I have a class:

```
class Sitestats(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int,String,String,Int,String)](tag, "SITESTATS"){
  def id = column[Int]("STAT_ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def url = column[String]("STAT_URL")
  def httpstatus = column[String]("STAT_HTTPSTATUS")
  def contentlength = column[Int]("STAT_CONTENTLENGTH")
  def description = column[String]("STAT_DESC")

  def * : ProvenShape[(Int,String,String,Int,String)] = (id,url,httpstatus,contentlength,description)
}
```

Allowing me to do (using slick)

```
 sitestats.ddl.create
 sitestats += ((3534,"http://google.com","TEST",22,"TEST"))
 sitestats += ((234,"http://google7.com","404",22,"TEST"))
 println(sitestats.list)
```

resulting in the expected (snip):

```
[info] List((1,http://google.com,TEST,22,TEST),(2,http://google7.com,404,22,TEST))
```

I would like httpstatus to be able to be null, so I changed the line to

```
def httpstatus = column[Option[String]]("STAT_HTTPSTATUS")
```

resulting in

```
[error]  found   : (scala.slick.lifted.Column[Int], scala.slick.lifted.Column[String], scala.slick.lifted.Column[Option[String]], scala.slick.lifted.Column[Int], scala.slick.lifted.Column[String])
[error]  required: scala.slick.lifted.ProvenShape[(Int, String, String, Int, String)]
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Try update like this:

```
def * : ProvenShape[(Int,String,Option[String],Int,String)] = (id,url,httpstatus,contentlength,description)
```

You forgot to update your table definition. :)

## Update

```
sitestats += (Some(234,"http://google7.com","404",22,"TEST"))
```

Comment: Results in [error]  found   : String("404")
    [error]  required: Option[String]
    [error]       sitestats += ((234,"http://google7.com","404",22,"TEST"))